# looking for a quick way to populate a std::list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ program where I'm populating a `std::list` with the addresses of a memory pool.

I have an implementation that works using `std::generate` and it's not bad, but it can be a bit slow with large pools of small allocation blocks.

```
/// fill the allocation list with the memory addresses of each block
struct fill
{
    fill( void* start, ulong alloc ) 
        : start_( start ), 
          alloc_( alloc ), 
          count_( 0 ) 
    {
    };

    void* operator()()
    {
        return ( void* )( ( ulong ) start_ + ( count_++ ) * alloc_ );
    }

    /// starting address
    void* start_;
    /// size of the blocks
    ulong alloc_;
    /// internal counter
    int count_;
}; // struct fill

ulong begin = 0;            // beginning address
ulong max_size = 0x1000;    // maximum memory pool size (4KB)
ulong block_size = 0x20;    // size of each memory block (32B)

std::list< void* > memory;
memory.resize( max_size / block_size ); // 128 memory blocks
std::generate( memory.begin(), memory.end(), fill( begin, block_size ) );
```

I was just wondering if anybody had a faster or more efficient method of filling the linked-list.

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Why are you using a `list` instead of a `vector`? What exactly does *slow* mean? You are allocating 128 small blocks of memory. That should be very fast regardless of the data-structure.

Comment: This effort seems misguided. `std::list` will do its own allocation for each node, so your memory pool won't save you anything (it will probably be slower than normal allocations)

Comment: it is not strictly related with list but have you consider loki small object allocator?

Comment: For those that require context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034156/suggestions-for-improving-an-allocator-algorithm-implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code passes over the list twice instead of once.

So it might help to define an iterator that returns the addresses, so that everything is done in a single pass:

```
struct blocks {
    void *current;
    size_t increment;

    blocks(void* start, size_t size = 0) : current(start), increment(size) {}

    bool operator==(const blocks &rhs) const { return current == rhs.current; }
    bool operator!=(const blocks &rhs) const { return current != rhs.current; }
    void *operator*() const { return current; }
    blocks &operator++() {
        current = (void*)( (char*)current + increment );
        return *this;
    }
};

std::list<void*> memory(blocks(begin, block_size), blocks(max_size));
```

(Code not tested, and I've left out some of the stuff you need in order to be a proper iterator - it needs tagging if nothing else, and post-increment is usually welcome.)

Currently it's just a ForwardIterator (or would be, if it was tagged). You could make it a RandomAccessIterator easily enough, but you'd have to give the end iterator the correct size. If you used a container of `char(*)[block_size]` instead of a container of `void*`, then I think you could just use a `boost::counting_iterator<char(*)[block_size]>` to populate it.

Fundamentally, though, `std::list` is moderately slow at this. Unless you're going to do insert/remove in the middle (which seems unnecessary for a memory pool free list - if all the blocks are the same size you should be able to always add and remove at the end), you might do better with a vector or deque, or at least with an intrusive linked list.

Comment: Steve, isn't `std::list` a linked-list itself?

Comment: Also, don't you need to implement `operator!=`?

Comment: @Nawaz: (1) yes, but it is not an intrusive linked list. (2) yes, that lack will almost certainly prevent the `list` constructor from compiling, so I'll add it.

Comment: I've switched to a `std::deque` and implemented your clever method of using the iterator constructor. It is faster, thank you!

Comment: Ohhh.. I didn't know the [intrusive and non-intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html) terminologes. thanks. and +1